# How to get an String value from another String

Tags: java, android, string

This could sound strange but actually is quite simple.

Short description: I have a class variable called

```
public static final String ACCELEROMETER_X = "AccX";
```

In one function I do this, which get me "ACCELEROMETER_X" from a enum (sensors is an arrayList of my enum).

```
for i...
    columns = columns + sensors.get(i).name()
```

The point is I want to introduce in columns not "ACCELEROMETER_X", but "AccX". Any idea? I know I could do it using switch and cases but my enum has more than 30 values so Id rather prefer other "cleaner" way to do it.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to accomplish and what you are doing in your loop.

Comment: Once you realise that an `enum` is just syntactic sugar for a class, as Rohit has shown, then it all becomes easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `enum` constant to be replaced with that string value, a better way would be keep that string as a field in the `enum` itself:

```
enum Sensor {
    ACCELEROMETER_X("AccX"),
    // Other constants
    ;

    private final String abbreviation;

    private Sensor(final String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
}
```

And instead of:

```
sensors.get(i).name()
```

use this:

```
sensors.get(i).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : If you keep the value in class

Create a Map with key as the id (ACCELEROMETER_X) and value as "AccX" and when you get the value from the Enum use that to find the value from the map using name() as the key.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

map.put("ACCELEROMETER_X","AccX");

//some place where you want value from name
map.get(enumInstance.name());
```

Solution 2: Change the enum (more preferable)

```
enum Some{

   ACCELEROMETER_X("AccX");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `enum` add this

```
public String getAccelerometerX (){
    return ACCELEROMETER_X ;
}
```

and then:

```
for i... columns = columns + sensors.get(i).getAccelerometerX ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to get the value of a field from its name which you have in a `String`, if that's the case, you could do something like this:

```
public static final String ACCELEROMETER_X = "AccX";

// ...

Field field = MyClassName.class.getField("ACCELEROMETER_X");
String value = (String)field.get(new MyClassName());

System.out.println(value); // prints "AccX"
```

Of course you'll have to catch some Exceptions.